# How to test carousel in RTL?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to test carousel in React-testing-library.

I can't check whether state is changed in RTL like enzyme does, so...

What I've done is just give carousel a scrollX and check whether it is changed

```
fireEvent.scroll(element, { target: { scrollX: 100 } });
// check
element.scrollLeft...
```

Is it collect or any ideas?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./Carousel.css";

export interface CarouselProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Carousel = ({ children }: CarouselProps) => {
  const carouselRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  let isDown = false;
  let startX = 0;
  let scrollLeft = 0;

  const onMouseDownCarousel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
    if (!carouselRef || !carouselRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    isDown = true;
    carouselRef.current.classList.add("active");
    startX = e.pageX - carouselRef.current.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = carouselRef.current.scrollLeft;
  };

  const onMouseLeaveCarousel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
    if (!carouselRef || !carouselRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    isDown = false;
    carouselRef.current.classList.remove("active");
  };

  const onMouseUpCarousel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
    if (!carouselRef || !carouselRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    isDown = false;
    carouselRef.current.classList.remove("active");
  };

  const onMouseMoveCarousel: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
    if (!carouselRef || !carouselRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    if (!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - carouselRef.current.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
    carouselRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="carousel"
      onMouseDown={onMouseDownCarousel}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeaveCarousel}
      onMouseUp={onMouseUpCarousel}
      onMouseMove={onMouseMoveCarousel}
      ref={carouselRef}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: RTL differs from Enzyme in that you test user behaviour and expectations rather than the internals of the component. So, in part this enforces component accessibility by design. To test your carousel you could look for the carousel UI button `screen.getByRole('button', { name: /scroll left/i })` then trigger this using `userEvent.click` and assert if the content you expected to be shown is shown. This does however depend on how each carousel item is shown when navigating between them. If the content is displayed differently then this technique may not work and you'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: There are escape hatches which allow you to test for the presence of classes and IDs, but I'd suggest taking a look at the [RTL docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about) for better ways to query your content. And further to this, if its your own carousel code then perhaps take a look at the W3C example here to see how you can structure it to be accessible, and thus, easier to test with RTL:  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/carousel/carousel-1.html